# How would I get the difference between two dates in days and excluding weekends?

Tags: google-bigquery

How would I get the difference between two dates in days and excluding weekends?

For context, this is for the purposes of Service Level Agreement (SLA) monitoring between the date that the ticket is created and closed.

Comment: What programming language and/or framework did you try? What is your code? What problems did you have running that code?

Answer (score 2):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION CUSTOM_DATE_DIFF(startDate DATE, endDate DATE) AS ((
  SELECT
    1 + DATE_DIFF(endDate, startDate, DAY) -
    2 * DATE_DIFF(endDate, startDate, WEEK) -
    IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM startDate) = 1, 1, 0) -
    IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM endDate) = 7, 1, 0)
));
WITH test AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-05-01' startDate, DATE '2018-05-11' endDate
)
SELECT 
  startDate, 
  endDate, 
  CUSTOM_DATE_DIFF(startDate, endDate) diff
FROM test
```

Comment: I really like your solution with the TEMP FUNCTION. It keeps the code nice and clean. And it still works 5 years after you originally posted it 